# The JQuery remains after deleting JQuery library

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I recently started coding in php and today I decided to work with JQuery. I had a perfeclty working top_bar made in css, but when i inserted the code

```
<script 
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" 
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

new bugs appeared in my header class and the style.css file stopped working, hence I decided to delete the package from external libraries, but the styles still don't work.

[After inspecting it seems like the code remained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk90N.jpg)

`header.php` code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rater</title>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

        <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top_bar">
            <div class = "logo">
                <a href="index.php">Rater</a>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#">Messages</a>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking at the inspector window on your screen shot, it looks like you may have not removed it as the link to the jQuery file is after your top_bar. Can you check your code after the top_bar closes?

Comment: There is nothing after except of </body>

Comment: The thing is that the code worked perfectly fine until i pressed alt+enter when my mouse was on the link.

Answer (score 0):

It may have set in the cache in the browser. Remove the script tag and check, in another browser